# Java Android SQL query

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I need to create a statement like "select * from names where surename in ('doe', 'smith'...) using SQLiteDatabase object and after two hours of googling i could not find a way how to use IN keyword and insert multiple options into the query. Any tips, how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

JV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic example using `IN` clause

```
String[] names = { "doe", "smith" }; 
String query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    + " WHERE name IN (" + makePlaceholders(names.length) + ")";
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, names);
```

and this is the `makePlaceholders()` method:

```
String makePlaceholders(int len) {
    if (len < 1) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No placeholders");;¿
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * 2 - 1);
        sb.append("?");
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append(",?");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```